# how to make my own custom calendar in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios6

Hi can anyone help in developing my own calendar,i have seen tapku library and also other different options available,but i am not getting anything .can anyone suggest me from where i have to start and what approach to follow i just want to create a custom calendar.
I want something that can push me to start with this.

Comment: you can use a gridview for achieving this like i did in one of my application to give a feel of custom calendar.

Comment: can u please help me..what approach i have to follow and how that should be initiated.

Comment: First try and if you fail in try than ask question with enough information. There are many ios calendar available on internet try that learn from that than try to implement your own. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar

Comment: @CRDave i am able to integrate the tapku calendar in my app but i want to make  my own but i dont know from where to start..i just want to know the steps and things i need to know before starting.

Comment: you can take a gridview with cell of dates and show it in any viewcontroller and gridview also give you the tapped cell index it's concept is just like tableview.

Comment: There is no algorithm for developing custom controls. That depend on what kind of calendar you want to create. To learn there is only one option learn from demos.

Answer (score 4):

Creating Calendar functionality is a lot of work, why don't you use something like [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) or [tapku](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tapku-calendar). I once used Kal and it works fine.

Anyways, if you want to create your own you should consider following

- **Decide on calendar view** - whether you want to show grid view, list view, or day view.
- **Create event** - where do you want to add events, in iPhone Calendar or in your own database. If it is your own database then you have to create your database and write procedures to add events.
- **Set Notifications** - If it is your own database then you have to set notifications for alerts.

These are just few things came in my mind. What unique thing will you offer in your calendar. If not then it is just the waste of time!!!!

Comment: Both the code are not working any more can u plz let me know how to utilize the code (Kal and Tapku)......

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the codes are not working? They have instructions on how to add it in the project and all...

Comment: I downloaded the tapku library. all the default framework are like @import uikit. then I remove all such type of line with proper one. but then other peculiar issue raises. can u have any other well working sample code